# How to click save button in selenium python? Keep getting StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am pretty new to Selenium. I am trying to save the result from a query to a csv file. However, I can't even click save that will open the drop down box. I tried the code below  and get StaleElementReferenceException error

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



DRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/")


search = driver.find_element_by_id("id_term")
search_term = """covid"""
search_term = search_term.replace("”",'"')
search_term = search_term.replace("“",'"')
search_term = "".join(search_term.splitlines())
search_term=re.sub(' {2,}', ' ', search_term)
search.send_keys(search_term)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

click_button = search.find_element_by_link_text("save-results-panel-trigger").click()
```

What I am trying to do is once I click the save button, I want to select "All results" from selection and create file. However, I can't even click save button

I also tried

```
click_button = search.find_elememt_by_id("save-results-panel-trigger").click() 

click_button = search.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="save-results-panel-trigger"]')
```

still no luck

When I inspect the elements for save this is what I get:

```
<button id="save-results-panel-trigger" type="button" class="save-results save-results-panel-trigger" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="save-action-panel" data-ga-category="save_share" data-ga-action="save" data-ga-label="open">
      Save
    </button>
```

Comment: just use this part: find_elememt_by_id("save-results-panel-trigger").click()   Search is stale after you hit enter, since the DOM will update.  You may also need to use a webdriverwait to wait for the button to be clickable.

Comment: @pcalkins, thank you for taking time to respond. The find_element has to go after clicking enter since that is a button after we have a result ( at least to what i think) Am I wrong in my understanding?

Comment: when you send the Return button, the page is likely updating. However it's likely racing against the find_element_by_link_text operation which is why you're getting a stale element error. Add in a wait to allow the page to load/refresh before clicking save

Comment: to be clear it's that you are using "search.find..."  (instead of driver.find...) After you hit enter, your "search" webelement reference will be stale as the DOM will update due to a standard page load, or a javascript update.  (if it's a javascript update, you'll want to use the wait as DMart suggests.)